# Random function outputs same number.

Tags: php, random, numbers, duplicates, output

I am using the following code to generate random number:

```
$random = mt_rand(1000000000,10000000000);
```

It works perfectly on localhost, but on the server It outputs exactly same number. Is there any thing I can do to prevent duplicate results?
Actually i tried to use

```
mt_srand();
```

But i did not know how to use it.

Comment: If in doubt how to use it. [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-srand.php)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are on PHP >= 7 then you can use random_int() to generate a random integer this also accepts the same arguments as mt_rand.

If you want to use mt_srand then you could seed it with a Unix timestamp in milliseconds and then run your mt_rand() function. For example.

```
mt_srand(microtome());
$rand = mt_rand(1, 100000);
```

Answer (score 0):

"Random" numbers are not really random, they're pseudo-random.  Look for an instruction to "seed" the generator with a varying value, like something time-based, to get different values each time.

The documentation says: "Many random number generators of older libcs have dubious or unknown characteristics and are slow. The mt_rand() function is a drop-in replacement for the older rand(). It uses a random number generator with known characteristics using the » Mersenne Twister, which will produce random numbers four times faster than what the average libc rand() provides."

Read the [manual on mt_srand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-srand.php) and choose a seed (like seconds or milliseconds or ticks or whatever) that will vary from invocation to invocation.